# How to save a OneToOne Model when given another Model field?

Tags: django, django-models

Using this exmaple:

```
class ModelA(Model):
     name = CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class ModelB(Model):
     modela = OneToOneField(ModelA)
     otherfield = ManyToManyField(...)
     ...
```

Then, how does one save a ModelB form when given a ModelA name?

I tried something like this in my views:

```
def modelbSave(request, modelA_name):
        modelA = ModelA.objects.get(name=modelA_name)
        modelB = ModelB.objects.get(modela=modelA)

        if request.method == "POST":
             # Edit existing modelB or save a new one
             modelB_form = ModelBForm(request.POST, instance=modelB)

             if modelB_form.is_valid():
                   modelB = modelB_form.save(commit=False)
                   modelB.modela = modelA  # save modelA relationship
                   modelB.save()
                   modelB_form.save_m2m()   # save other m2m relationships in modelB

        else:
             ....
```

But I get the error on this line:

```
modelB = ModelB.objects.get(modela=modelA)
```

With error saying:

```
Exception Value: modelB matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: Well, that's telling you there's no matching ModelB instance. Why are you attempting to read it from the database before you create it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm trying to do a create_or_update sort of thing. If the modelB doesn't exist for a given modelA name, then the view will just go ahead and create it. But if it does exist, then the view will do an update. At the time of saving, the ModelB may or may not exist given the ModelA name, so this view function will deal with that.

Comment: OK, so catch the DoesNotExist exception and set instance to None, then.